# How to dump data to a workbook and save a copy?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a record set `UserTab` that I want to copy to an excel spreadsheet (it has all needed formatting) and then save a copy

```
Dim templatewb As Workbook
templatewb = application.open("C:\ \ .xlsx") // I also tried add

templatewb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells("A1").CopyFromRecordset UserTab 
templatewb.close  savechanges:=true filename:="c:...copyOfATemplate.xls"
```

I get the following

`Method 'Save' of object '_Workbook' failed`

Comment: Try explicitly saving the workbook. I see you're opening the file as an xlsx and then saving it as xls. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim templatewb As Workbook

Set templatewb = workbooks.open("C:\stuff\templt.xlsx") 'need Set here...

templatewb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset UserTab 

templatewb.SaveAs  "C:\stuff\copyOfATemplate.xls"
```

Comment: +1 sorry i made a typo . i had `set ` there . Anyway, i tried `SaveAs` but got the same error . I read that Microsoft acknowleged this as a bug or something http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292482

Comment: The error you link to is related to saving a *worksheet* object, not a workbook.